# c++ empty console when i run it

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Empty console when i open the program. 
I am using Visual studio 2012 and there is no bug. When i run there is no output and there is no bug too! Help!

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool wex;
int main()
{
    int quas =1;

    while(quas<4);

    cout << "Do You want to continue? Y/N\n";
    char answer = 0;
    cin >> answer;

    switch(answer){
        case'y':
            return true;
        case'n':
            return false;
        default:
            cout << " Ok, No right?\n";
            ++quas;

    }

    cout<<"Ok , It's A NO!\n";
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Your indentation, please fix it.

Comment: There is a bug ... it is called an infinite loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
while(quas<4);
```

is equivalent to

```
while(quas<4)
    ;
```

i.e. an infinite loop

You need to remove the `;` that immediately follows the `while` and add braces `{}` around the lines you want to include in your loop.

Comment: Thx! I can't spot my mistake, sorry for that!

Comment: Why is my program window disappear after i type 3 Y(yes)?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking but `'Y'` has a different character code from `'y'` so will be handled by the `default` case in your `switch`.  Also, when your loop completes, your program will print a message then immediately exit.  If you want it to wait before exiting, wait for the user to press a key after the loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
while(quas<4);
```

This will loop forever.